# Jquery ajax get request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am new to jquery and php, I have two input fields, zip and city, the city shall output a value based from the zip that the user input. The jquery script shall call a URL: http://domain.com/city?zip.php="zip; so that zip.php will return an echo value that will output to the city input field.

I tried using ajax getXMLHTTP. some times it works but sometimes not

Please Refer to the following code snippet below:

```
 <input type="text" id="zip_code" name="zip_code" /> 

 <input type="text" id="city" name="city" />

 <script type="text/javascript">

 // Some Jquery code here for ajax get request to http://domain.com/city?zip.php

 </script>
```

Comment: if you use jquery just use `$.get()` 
you have to show us some code, or we cant help you.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jQuery.get`, documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get). In the success handler, use the data argument to populate the city input.

Sample:

```
$.get('http://domain.com/city.php?zip='+$('#IdOfZipInput').val(), function (data){
    $('#IdOfCityInput').val(data);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

if you are using jquery the use $.ajax option instead of getXMLHTTP

```
function passzipvalue(zip)
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url : 'http://domain.com/city.php='
                data:"zip="+zip,
                success: function(msg){
                    $("#formsData").html(msg);

                }
            });
}
```

something like this or

```
$.get('http://domain.com/city.php?zip='+zip,function (msg){
    $('#formsData').html(msg);
});
```

if you want to populate it in some input fields use `.val` instead of `.html`

Comment: Is `#formsData` an input field? If yes, *only* `.val()` works; otherwise *only* `.html()` or `.text()` works! Besides that, you usually need jsonp when retrieving data from another domain.

Answer (score 1):

```
            $.ajax({
                url: 'url',
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    //show loading
                }
            }).done(function (data, xhr) {
                //hide loading
                
                //success

            }).fail(function (xhr) {
                //hide loading

                //error

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/). For example:

```
var zip = $('#zip').val();
$.get('http://domain.com/city.php?zip='+zip,function (data){
    $('#city').val(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use the jquery ajax

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'sample/test.php',//your url
       data: data,//data to be post
       cache: false,
       success: function(html) { 
         alert(html);//response from the server
  }

      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://domain.com/city.php?zip='+zip,
  type: get,
  success: function(data){
    $("div").html(data);
  }
});

use this data will be displayed
```

Answer (score 0):

If its a constantly updating element then use jquery.post as ie caches the "get" results.

jQuery.post('call.php',{ action: "get"}, function (data) {

```
        jQuery('#content').append(data);

    });
```

FInd the tutorial here http://vavumi.com/?p=257